# Node/Express authenticate Google email address

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express.js, oauth

Trying to set up express server that will authenticate a user's Google email before proceeding.

The code below works, but is there any way to make it more elegant?

The whole `new Promise` thing feels clunky.

Still wrapping my head around async functions. All the `googleapis` functions are async, so I feel there's a better way.

I wanted to "wrap" the whole `getEmail` inside the `app.get('/oauth2callback'...` but I'm confused by how to "bubble up" a response from several levels of nested async calls so that the `app.get` call can send the final `res` to client (if that makes any sense.)

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const express = require('express');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  oauthID, oauthSecret, // from google dev console
  "http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback" //callback URL
);

async function getEmail(auth, code) {
  const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)
  oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    google.people('v1').people.get(
      { auth: auth, resourceName: 'people/me', personFields: 'emailAddresses' },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) { resolve(err) }
        email = res.data.emailAddresses && res.data.emailAddresses.length && res.data.emailAddresses[0].value
        resolve(email);
      }
    )
  });
}

const app = express();

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const URL = await oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
  });
  res.send(`<a href="${URL}">login</a>`);
});

app.get('/oauth2callback', (req, res) => {
  getEmail(oauth2Client, req.query.code)
    .then(r => res.send('••Your Google email is: ' + r))
    .catch(e => res.send('••Error: ' + e))
})


app.listen(3000)
```

UPDATE: A few hours later, here's what I came up with:

```
const authURL = auth.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']
});
//...
app.get('/oauth2callback', (req, res) => {
  auth.getToken(req.query.code)
    .then(r => {
      auth.setCredentials(r.tokens)
      google.people('v1').people.get(
        { auth: auth, resourceName: 'people/me', personFields: 'emailAddresses' }
      )
        .then(r => {
          email = r.data.emailAddresses && r.data.emailAddresses.length && r.data.emailAddresses[0].value;
          res.json({email: email})
        })
        .catch(e => res.send('••Error in people: ' + e))
    })
    .catch(e => {
      res.send(`Problem logging in, <a href="${authURL}">try again</a>`)
    })
})
```

This works, too ... but is it "better"?

Comment: can you use [`await` inside `getEmail(auth, code) {}` for the `get()` request instead of creating a promise](https://javascript.info/async-await#await) ? If you use several times `await`, the function execution is stopped until receiving the callback?